# color dodge function in mix RGB node

Tags: shader-nodes

Hey guys I have a doubt about[image] the color dodge function in the mix RGB node in the blender. The formula for the color dodge is a/(1-b), but when I change the first input to 0.2 and the second input to 1 then the color dodge function outputs like the image I have provided down below, but based on the formula 0.2/(1-1) gives the value undefined therefore I have a great confusion in the working principle of the color dodge function, I think my formula does not consider the fac value, But I don't know which formula considers the fac value, Some members gave a link to blender source code but I don't understand codes that much, please guys help me out!

Comment: The *Fac* is a factor that indicates how strong the effect is (How much Color Dodge do you want? 0=original, 1=full effect. You can enter a number > 1 to amplify it). There is no *undefined* in Blender. In the case x/(1-1) the result is clipped to white as also described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Dodge_and_burn): *"The Color Dodge blend mode divides the bottom layer by the inverted top layer. ... Blending any color with white gives white. Blending with black does not change the image. The operation is not invertible due to possible clipping of highlights.  ..."*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys I found out the formula for COLOR DODGE myself with the help of source code,the formula is

```
        Result = a / 1 - fb.
```

Comment: Hi! Would you mind writing out all of the available formulas? I know the formulas but I don't know how to insert the factor f. Here's my post asking for help: https://blenderartists.org/t/what-are-the-exact-functions-of-blend-modes/1485612 Thank you!